# hadoop - Compress parquet files using bzip

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, parquet, hadoop2

I have a huge databaes which I am trying to copy to other cluster using distcp. However, due to limited bandwidth I am thinking to compress this files using bzip (it's already in snappy compression. on top of snappy compression.

Is there a way I can do this on hdfs it self. Rather than moving files to local file system and then applying compression.

Comment: If I were you I'd first give it a try locally on a small sample, becasue I'm not sure using bzip compression on top of snappy will help much (you may save 10%, but not much more).

Comment: @0x26res in theory it should give ~30% compression. which is more than enough as we are talking about data in peta bytes.

Comment: you mean you want to compress the data just for the one-time distcp? I'm pretty sure the compression and then de-compression (on the new cluster) will take more time than copy the original files. But you never know until you try :)

Comment: @shay__ yes. i just want to give it a try. do you know how can I achieve this ?